# Enigmail 1.5 / Thunderbird 17 line wrap signing order

Tags: thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

I experience serious trouble with line-wraps in thunderbird when using enigmail.

It seems that there is something wrong with the order of the follwing steps:

1. I write a text (without caring about having long lines or not)
2. I tell enigmail to sign the message
3. I hit send

What happens now is:

1. Enigmails signs the message
2. Thunderbird now adds line-wraps (thus breaking the signature)
3. Thunderbird sends e-mail

I'd like that my E-Mails get wrapped at max. 72-chars before enigmail signs the message. How can I configure this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Option no. 1: use word wrapping.

Option no. 2: switch to using PGP/MIME instead of PGP/in-line for signing and encrypting.  PGP/MIME handles things like long lines, HTML messages (if you really must send them), attachments and extended character sets better than PGP/in-line does.

PGP/MIME is vastly superior to in-line, but the only drawback is that some mail clients, especially on phones and certain webmail interfaces, just can't handle it at all.  I use PGP/MIME with exceptions for a few recipients and some mailing lists.